# Laravel 2 different htaccess RewriteRule Problem

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

In a project where we are using Laravel, we want a specific url to run another php file. But the url we want is constantly entering Laravel. We can't change project's DocumentRoot so we have 2 different .htaccess files.

When request come to api/v1/user/donate we want run /home/userName/project/subdomains/client/user.php. How can we do it?

Project Root: /home/userName/public_html

Project Root .htaccess file content;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# That was ONLY to protect you from 500 errors
# if your server did not have mod_rewrite enabled

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# NOT needed unless you're using mod_alias to redirect

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
# Direct all requests to /public folder
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php80” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php80 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Project's public folder .htaccess file content;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

We used this rule for both .htaccess file but it didn't work;

```
RewriteRule ^api/v1/user/donate$ /subdomains/client/user.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: And _where_ in those files did you try this? In the first one doesn't make much sense, IMHO, and in the second one, it would of course have to come _before_ the general rewrite to the index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Alias "/api/v1/user/donate" "/home/userName/project/subdomains/client/user.php"
```

Comment: We can't use apache config. We can use just .htaccess

Comment: @BurakErikan you cannot achieve that without having access to apache config

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```